# Const variables must be initialized with a constant value

Tags: flutter, dart

When I do something like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const kBaseColor = Colors.deepPurple;
const kBase300 = Colors.deepPurple[300]; // there is an error
```

> error: Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.
> (const_initialized_with_non_constant_value at [myprogect]
> lib\ui\widgets\constants.dart:4)

Isn't it possible to assign a shade of the color as const variable?

Comment: check this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27733

Comment: You can have a look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494710/color-shades-are-not-constant-values-in-flutter#:~:text=When%20you%20use%20Colors.,a%20shade%20instead%2C%20i.e.%20Colors.&text=This%20is%20important%2C%20for%20example,default%20value%20must%20be%20constant.

Comment: @RobertSandberg well, it's arguable what's easy to use - Color(0xFF42A5F5) or just final keyword :)

Comment: We'll, using final isn't an answer to the question, final and const isn't the same thing.

Comment: Because he explicitly asked for a const variable. I'm not saying that using final isn't a viable option depending on use case. Given the information it isn't clear that he wanted to know because of a particular use case or just to increase his understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `final` instead of that,
the reason is If the value you have is computed at runtime
you can not use a `const` for it.
you can use final instead of that
like this

```
final kBase300 = Colors.deepPurple[300];
```